# How do check admin creds in flask blueprint

Tags: flask

How do you check admin credentials before rendering any templates?

```
admin = Blueprint('admin', __name__, url_prefix='/Admin' ,static_folder='static', static_url_path='/static/adminUI', template_folder='templates')



@admin.route('/')
def login():

    return redirect(url_for('admin.login'))


@admin.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    admin = Admin.query.filter_by(username='Admin').first()
    passwrd = request.form.get('password')
    if admin:
        if not check_password_hash(admin.password , passwrd):
            return render_template('admin_login.html')
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('admin.dashboard'))
    else:
        return render_template('admin_login.html')
```

typing `127.0.0.1:5000/Admin` in the browser takes me directly to the dashboard which is not good because anyone can do that, my goal is to have more than one admin and prevent non-admins from accessing the dashboard

models.py

```
class Admin(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Administators"
    id =  db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100) , unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(200) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flask-JWT: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JWT/

You must generate the jwt token in the login procedure, then you need to pass it via the header of the http request

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_jwt import JWT, jwt_required, current_identity

#... see the quickstart section to see how to setup jwt... https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JWT/

@app.route('/protected')
@jwt_required()
def protected():
    return '%s' % current_identity
```